# Node.JS MongoDB Find Function Not Running

Tags: node.js, mongodb, find

I'm attempting to find data from a MongoDB Collection using Node.JS. However, the issue is that it's simply not working, no errors, no incorrect results. Just nothing happening at all.

```
const mongo = require("mongodb").MongoClient
const mongoURL = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.route("/fetchplayer").get(fetchPlayer)
}

async function fetchPlayer(request, response) {
    const mongoClient = await mongo.connect(mongoURL)
    const project = request.query.project
    const id = request.query.id

    const playersDB = mongoClient.db("RopePlayers")
    const playersCollection = playersDB.collection(project)

    const query = { "player" : id}

    playersCollection.find(query).toArray(function (error, result) {
        if (error) throw error

        console.log(result)
    })

}
```

I have logged all variables to make sure they are working an all have the correct values. My collection is currently empty, however according to MongoDB documentation I should still receive an empty array as a result.

I have referenced several sources of documentation includes [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_query.asp), [MonogoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) Documentation and here on StackOverflow, however to no success.

Comment: where's your mongoURL is defined ?

`const mongoClient = await mongo.connect(mongoURL)`

Comment: Sorry I just forgot to put it into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like below:

```
const res = await playersCollection.find(query).toArray();

response.json(res);
```